# How to calculate these possibilities

Tags: probability

let say there re two soccer teams,A and B
team A scores in 60% of their games and concedes a goal on 40% of them
team B scores in 30% of their games and concedes a goal on 55% of them

what re the possibilities on a match between them for each team to score a goal
and what re the possibilities for both teams to score?

Comment: can someone please answer my question?

Comment: I have no idea why there haven't been any comments or answers yet. But if you can show what you have attempted, your question will be much better received.

Comment: thank you for the answer Toby, i m just trying to figure out the probabilities and the connection of scoring between 2 teams if we know the % number of goals every team scores and concedes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Team $A$ scores in $60 \%$ of their games. Given this, the probability, or the likelihood of them scoring in this game will also be $60 \%$, or $0.6$. The same applies for team $B$.

For the second part of the question, you have to use the multiplication rule of probability. This is to say, $P(A \ \text{and B}) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$, or the probability of *both* event $A$ and event $B$ happening is the product of their individual probabilities.

See if you can apply this to the question.

Comment: it does,thank you for your answer Toby i m curious how the number of goals a team concedes affect the equation
or it doesnt at all?

Comment: If the percentage of goals scored to total goals is still the same, then it will not affect the equation.